# How can i pass two values from select box using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi i have the following code but i am not able to access the values in my request.php file from this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.location").change(function(){
        var Did = $("input[name='district']").val();
        var selectedLocation = $(".location option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "request.php",
            data: {location : selectedLocation, Did:Did}, 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#response").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

and my request.php is calling the data like this

```
    if(isset($_GET["location"]))
{
    $i=0;
    $bfrom = $_GET["location"];
    $did= $_GET["Did"];
$sql = "SELECT distinct stopname FROM `route` WHERE `rfrom` LIKE '$bfrom' and did=$did";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: use json to pass multiple values

Answer (score 0):

first off, and most importantly, for security you need to parameterize your query. See [PHP: Prepared statements and stored procedures](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Secondly, your LIKE argument needs to be preceded and followed by % - eg '%$bfrom%' - this enables "wildcard" data search [MySQL Wildcards](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Lastly, you need to echo a response in the AJAX call, in order for the receiving javascript to pick it up :)